# shm_memory + mmap + table + struct

Tags: c, struct, void

I'm trying to access a table in a shared memory zone created thanks to shm_open and containing a structure containing the `void ** table`.
I've initialized it thanks to various malloc
But when I try to access it I get a segmentation fault.
I'm guessing it's because of a memcpy instruction, but I don't know why. Please can someone help me?

There is the part where it bug.

```
if(channel->index > 0){
    if(DEBUG){
        printf("channel_recv : channel->index > 0 (%d) \n",channel->index);
    }
    if(memcpy(data,channel->tampon[0],channel->eltsize)==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    printf("apres memcpy \n");
    defile(channel);
    return 1;
}
```

And there is the initialization.

```
channel = (struct channel *)malloc(sizeof(struct channel));
channel->tampon = malloc(size * sizeof(void *));
for(i = 0 ; i < size;i++){
    channel->tampon[i] = malloc(eltsize * sizeof(void));
}
```

The "defile" function move every element in it to the left.

Comment: And o you set `channel->eltsize` to a non-zero value too somewhere?

Comment: yes channel->eltsize and channel->size are given and I test if they're not 0 or negative.Actually the part where it bugs concerns the memcpy and more especially the channel->tampon overtime I tried to access it I have a segmentation fault

Comment: This code looks a bit iffy... You may want to include more context such as the channel struct definition. Also how much memory do you intend to allocate with sizeof(void)?

Comment: Storing pointer values in shared memory areas makes no sense. The values mean nothing outside the program that writes them. Other processes that attach&use the shared memory will have different objects at these addresses. (or none at all)

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization

```
    channel->tampon[i] = malloc(eltsize * sizeof(void));
```

is wrong.

**ISO/IEC 9899:201x**:

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   object type that cannot be completed.

…

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
>   a type, …